# Why is a server with listen(sockfd, 2) call able to accept 3 connections?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, connection

I am trying to understand how the `backlog` parameter in `int listen(int sockfd, int backlog);` affects how new connections are handled.

Here is my server program.

```
/* server.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main()
{
    int sockfd;
    int ret;
    int yes = 1;

    struct addrinfo hints, *ai;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    if ((ret = getaddrinfo(NULL, "8000", &hints, &ai)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(ret));
        return 1;
    }

    sockfd = socket(ai->ai_family, ai->ai_socktype, ai->ai_protocol);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        perror("server: socket");
        return 1;
    }

    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof yes) == -1) {
        perror("server: setsockopt");
        close(sockfd);
        return 1;
    }

    if (bind(sockfd, ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
        perror("server: bind");
        close(sockfd);
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(ai);

    if (listen(sockfd, 2) == -1) {
        perror("server: listen");
        close(sockfd);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("server: listening ...\n");
    printf("server: sleep() to allow multiple clients to connect ...\n");
    sleep(10);

    printf("server: accepting ...\n");
    while (1) {
        int connfd;
        struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
        socklen_t client_addrlen = sizeof client_addr;
        char buffer[1024];
        int bytes;

        connfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &client_addrlen);
        if (connfd == -1) {
            perror("server: accept");
            continue;
        }

        if ((bytes = recv(connfd, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("server: recv");
            continue;
        }

        printf("server: recv: %.*s\n", (int) bytes, buffer);
        close(connfd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my client program.

```
/* client.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sockfd;
    int ret;
    struct addrinfo hints, *ai;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s MSG\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((ret = getaddrinfo(NULL, "8000", &hints, &ai)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "client: getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(ret));
        return 1;
    }

    sockfd = socket(ai->ai_family, ai->ai_socktype, ai->ai_protocol);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        perror("client: socket");
        return 1;
    }

    if (connect(sockfd, ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
        perror("client: connect");
        close(sockfd);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("client: connected\n");

    if (send(sockfd, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]), 0) == -1) {
        perror("client: send");
        close(sockfd);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("client: send: %s\n", argv[1]);

    freeaddrinfo(ai);
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile and run these programs with the following script.

```
# run.sh
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE server.c -o server
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE client.c -o client 
./server &
sleep 1
./client hello1 &
sleep 1
./client hello2 &
sleep 1
./client hello3 &
sleep 1
./client hello4 &
sleep 1
./client hello5 &
sleep 5
pkill server
```

When I run the above script, I get this output.

```
$ sh run.sh 
server: listening ...
server: sleep() to allow multiple clients to connect ...
client: connected
client: send: hello1
client: connected
client: send: hello2
client: connected
client: send: hello3
client: connected
client: send: hello4
client: connected
client: send: hello5
server: accepting ...
server: recv: hello1
server: recv: hello2
server: recv: hello3
```

The output shows that while the server was sleeping between `listen()` and `accept()`, all five clients could successfully `connect()` and `send()` to the server. However, the server could `accept()` and `recv()` three clients only.

I don't understand the following.

1. The server program invokes `listen()` with the `backlog` parameter as `2`. Why did all five clients succeed in `connect()`-ing then? I was expecting only 2 `connect()`s to be successful.
2. Why was the server able to `accept()` and `recv()` from 3 clients instead of 2?

Comment: The backlog parameter is something like a buffer, that holds some pending connection requests until you actually accept them with "accept". You clear this backlog buffer when accepting a connection

Comment: @BalazsVago In my question, I haven't cleared any connection by accepting it when all the 5 connections arrive. 5 clients connect to the server but the server does not accept any connection for 10 seconds. How is it than all 5 clients have succeeded in `connect()`-ing and `send()`-ing even though the server has not accepted any connection? After 10 seconds, when the server begins accepting connections, why does it succeed in accepting only 3 out of 5 connections?

Comment: I'm almost sure that your test is faulted. I think that the `connect` functions "block" until `accept` actually accepted the connection... so this means that your client actually "sleeps" together with the server... make sure to use non-blocking sockets or threads in your test, otherwise your results will be incorrect.

Comment: @LoneLearner - Just to clarify, I think that your client code "pauses" the first time it calls `connect`. This "pause" remains in effect until the server calls `accept`. I think that the server never needs more than a single backlog buffer since the client is using "blocking" sockets and there's no concurrency involved.

Comment: Note that the behavior depends on the specific version of Linux.  I was working on an Amazon Linux system where the behavior changed on a kernel update.  Previously there was an implicit minimum value (8, as I recall).  Some code I inherited passed 0 and began failing as the value was now taken literally rather than set to the minimum.  This behavior change was due to off-the-shelf Linux code, not an Amazon specific change.

Comment: One more thing you should worry about is `return` value of `getaddrinfo` its not `-1` in case of failure, its non zero value. So you should check it against `!= 0`

Answer (score 5):

> The server program invokes listen() with the backlog parameter as 2.
>   Why did all five clients succeed in connect()-ing then?

`backlog` parameter is only a hint for `listen()`. From [POSIX doc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/listen.html):

> The backlog argument provides a hint to the implementation which the
>   implementation shall use to limit the number of outstanding
>   connections in the socket's listen queue. Implementations may impose a
>   limit on backlog and silently reduce the specified value. Normally, a
>   larger backlog argument value shall result in a larger or equal length
>   of the listen queue. Implementations shall support values of backlog
>   up to SOMAXCONN, defined in .

Answer (score 5):

When a client connects to the listening port, depending on the implementation of the socket stack, it may either:

1. hold the pending connection in the backlog, and complete the 3-way TCP handshake only when `accept()` is called to remove that client from the backlog.  This is the behavior you are expecting, and is how older systems behaved.
2. complete the handshake right away in the background and then store the fully connected connection in the backlog until `accept()` removes it.  This is the behavior your example appears to be exhibiting, and is not uncommon in modern systems.

According to the Linux [manpage for `listen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html):

> The behavior of the backlog argument on TCP sockets changed with Linux 2.2.  **Now it specifies the queue length for completely established sockets waiting to be accepted, instead of the number of incomplete connection requests**.  The maximum length of the queue for incomplete sockets can be set using `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog`.  When syncookies are enabled there is no logical maximum length and this setting is ignored.  See [tcp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) for more information.

So, in your case, all 5 connections are likely being completed in the background before you start calling `accept()`, thus allowing the clients to call `send()` (and may do so before they can detect that some of the connections are being dropped), but not all of the connections are able to remain in the backlog due to its small size.

Comment: Why is the server able to `accept()` and `recv()` 3 out of the 5 connections when the backlog has been set to 2 only?

Comment: What is the value of `tcp_max_syn_backlog` on your system? There is still a queue of incomplete connections, so it sounds like when the accept queue fills up with established connections, the remaining connections are held in the incomplete queue, so that when a connection is removed from the accept queue, the next available incomplete connection gets completed and pushed into the accept queue.

Comment: `net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 128` on my system. If next available incomplete connection gets completed and pushed into the accept queue, why is the server not able to `accept()` all 5 connections then? Why is it able to `accept()` only 3 connections?

Comment: Timing. The other connections have likely already been closed and removed from the queues before you can `accept()` them.

Answer (score 3):

The issue actually seems to be that the test isn't isolating the `backlog` that it assumes to be testing.

The test code in the question seems to use "blocking" sockets and concurrency is invoked by demonizing the client test, which might explain how another client "got in".

To correctly test the issue, it's important to have a concurrent model where we know how much stress is exerted on the system at any point in time.

It's also important that we only clear the `backlog` **once**, without waiting for the kernel to refill the backlog we allocated with the kernel's layer backlog.

Attached is a concurrent (threaded) client+server that both listens, connects (to itself) and prints out the messages.

This design makes it clear how much stress (5 connections) the server experiences concurrently.

To make it a bit clearer, I chose to avoid "blocking" sockets as far as the server thread is concerned. This way we can `accept` everything in the backlog and get a notification (an error value) when the backlog is empty.

On my platform (macOS), the results show that only two clients manage to connect to the server, conforming to the `listen(socked, 2)` backlog specification.

All the other clients fail because the kernel drops the connection when it can't push it into the (full) backlog... though we don't know the connections were dropped until `read` is attempted... also some of my error checks aren't perfect):

```
server: listening ...
server: sleep() to allow multiple clients to connect ...
client: connected
client: connected
client: connected
client: connected
client: connected
client: read error: Connection reset by peer
client: read error: Connection reset by peer
client: read error: Connection reset by peer
server: accepting ...
client 3: Hello World!
client 5: Hello World!
```

The connected clients (3 & 5 in this example) are dependent on the thread scheduler, so every time the test is performed a different pair of clients will manage to connect.

It's true that `connect` returns successfully, but `connect` seems to be optimistically implemented by the accepting kernel, as pointed out in @RemyLebeau's answer. On some systems (i.e. Linux and macOS), the kernel will complete the TCP/IP handshake before attempting to attach the connection to our listening socket's backlog (OR dropping it if the backlog is full).

This is easy to see on my system's output, where the "server: accepting..." message arrives after both the "connect" confirmation and the "Connection reset by peer" events.

The code for the test was:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

void *server_threard(void *arg);
void *client_thread(void *arg);

int main(void) {
  /* code */
  pthread_t threads[6];

  if (pthread_create(threads, NULL, server_threard, NULL))
    perror("couldn't initiate server thread"), exit(-1);
  sleep(1);
  for (size_t i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    if (pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, client_thread, (void *)i))
      perror("couldn't initiate client thread"), exit(-1);
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  }
  return 0;
}

/* will start listenning, sleep for 5 seconds, then accept all the backlog and
 * finish */
void *server_threard(void *arg) {
  (void)(arg);
  int sockfd;
  int ret;

  struct addrinfo hints, *ai;

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

  if ((ret = getaddrinfo(NULL, "8000", &hints, &ai)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(ret));
    exit(1);
  }

  sockfd = socket(ai->ai_family, ai->ai_socktype, ai->ai_protocol);
  if (sockfd == -1) {
    perror("server: socket");
    exit(1);
  }
  ret = 1;
  if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &ret, sizeof ret) == -1) {
    perror("server: setsockopt");
    close(sockfd);
    exit(1);
  }

  if (bind(sockfd, ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
    perror("server: bind");
    close(sockfd);
    exit(1);
  }

  freeaddrinfo(ai);

  /* Set the server to non_blocking state */
  {
    int flags;
    if (-1 == (flags = fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL, 0)))
      flags = 0;
    // printf("flags initial value was %d\n", flags);
    if (fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) < 0) {
      perror("server: to non-block");
      close(sockfd);
      exit(1);
    }
  }
  if (listen(sockfd, 2) == -1) {
    perror("server: listen");
    close(sockfd);
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("server: listening ...\n");
  printf("server: sleep() to allow multiple clients to connect ...\n");
  sleep(5);

  printf("server: accepting ...\n");
  int connfd;
  struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
  socklen_t client_addrlen = sizeof client_addr;
  /* accept up all connections. we're non-blocking, -1 == no more connections */
  while ((connfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,
                          &client_addrlen)) >= 0) {
    if (write(connfd, "Hello World!", 12) < 12)
      perror("server write failed");
    close(connfd);
  }
  close(sockfd);
  return NULL;
}

void *client_thread(void *arg) {
  (void)(arg);
  int sockfd;
  int ret;
  struct addrinfo hints, *ai;

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

  if ((ret = getaddrinfo(NULL, "8000", &hints, &ai)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "client: getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(ret));
    exit(1);
  }

  sockfd = socket(ai->ai_family, ai->ai_socktype, ai->ai_protocol);
  if (sockfd == -1) {
    perror("client: socket");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (connect(sockfd, ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
    perror("client: connect error");
    close(sockfd);
    fprintf(stderr, "client number %lu FAILED\n", (size_t)arg);
    return NULL;
  }
  printf("client: connected\n");
  char buffer[128];
  if (read(sockfd, buffer, 12) < 12) {
    perror("client: read error");
    close(sockfd);
  } else {
    buffer[12] = 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "client %lu: %s\n", (size_t)arg, buffer);
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two queues for `backlog`, one is for connections which have finished three-way handshake and the other is for `TCP` in `SYN_RCVD` state which havan't received `ACK` from the remote client. Sum of these two queue size must be less equal than `backlog`. When you call `accept`, `os` retrieve one `ESTABLISHED` connection from connected queue. So you can `accept` too many connections from the established queue. This is not inconsistent with the `backlog`.

Answer (score 2):

regarding:

```
listen( sock, 2).
```

and its' ability to handle 3 connections.

The `2` is how many connections can be in the queue.

When `listen()` first returns, there are the current connection and room in the queue for 2 more.

I.E. at total of 3 connections.

Comment: In the test code I posted, this is obviously not the case. If we call `accept` using a non-blocking socket, we see that we can accept only two connections before `accept` fails. There's no extra connection at the top of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

As your code sleep one second between each client, clients have time to finish and close their connections before the next one comes.

So the queue on server side (this is what backlog argument controls) is always empty.

Try again without "sleep" statements.

Comment: There is a `sleep(10)` right before entering the server loop.

Comment: No, the clients are not finishing and closing their connections before the next one comes. The server code sleeps for 10 seconds before accepting any connections. All 5 client connections arrive within these 10 seconds and none of these 5 client connections get time to finish and close their connections until the server code begins accepting connections after `sleep(10)` returns. Also, how do you explain why the server is able to `accept()` 3 connections only when 5 were attempted?